# Why is $|x| = -x$ when $x \rightarrow -\infty $

Tags: calculus, limits

I really despise maths, so bear with me. I'm not the greatest at it.

I emailed my Maths1003 (Calc I) prof to ask a question, and at least to me, he answered it in a riddle.

Question is: Evaluate the Limit: $$\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{|x|+x}{x+1}$$

But I don't understand how the absolute value can be negative. Doesn't that defeat the point of it being absolute?

Answer is $0$.

He did say that $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$, which I do understand.

Help!

Comment: The input of the absolute value can be negative. However, it's output will always be positive.

Comment: Calculate that expression explicitly when $x=-1$ and then when $x=-2$ and you should see what's going on.

Comment: First: not the best way to start a question, is it? Now, the idea of the absolute value is that $|x|$ represents the distance between $0$ and $x$. Notice that if $x$ is negative (for instance, $x=-2$), it does not make much sense to say "the distance is $-2$". Hence, by definition, when $x$ is a negative number we put $|x|=-x$, thus obtaining a POSITIVE number (in our example, $|-2|=-(-2)=2>0$).

Comment: @EthanBolker: No! NO! Don't calculate it at $x=-1$, because then the universe implodes!

Comment: @TonyK Oops. Sorry for asking the OP to destroy the universe ...

Answer (score 6):

> But I don't understand how the absolute value can be negative.

It's not. If $x$ is negative then $-x$ is positive.

For example:

$$
|{-2}| = -(-2) = 2.
$$

You can't conclude that a quantity is negative just because you see a
 "$-$" sign in front of it.

Comment: +1 for seeing the OP's fundamental problem. Hope my edit is OK with you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. By [definition of absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Definition_and_properties), if $x<0$ then $|x|=-x$. Therefore, for $x<0$, the sum $|x|+x$ is identically zero (and your limit is zero too).

Note that $-x$ is not always a negative number. It is negative if and only if $x$ is positive.

Comment: Which is different then the rule |-x| = x.

Comment: Yes, it is different. The correct definition is given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Definition_and_properties

Answer (score 0):

Since of interest is the limit of the function as $x \to -\infty$; it suffices to  check for $x < 0$. For, by definition, that we want to know to what number the function "stays around" for $x$ goes below every bound $<0$. Considering $x < 0$, we immediately notice that $|x| + x = 0$. Since the function is always $=0$ for $x < 0$, its limit as $x \to -\infty$ is $0$.

It is because it suffices to consider $x < 0$ in this case that you see $|x| = -x$. The reason is that if $x < 0$ then $-x > 0$; and $|x| = -x$ for all $x < 0$.